# How to install RAID driver for HP ProLiant Microserver Gen 8 after installation of OS

Tags: centos, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I installed CentOS 7 on my HP ProLiant Microserver Gen8 on a SSD. I'm using the internal SD card slot as boot device while all other partitions are located on my SSD to circumvent the limitations of the storage controller. After days of OS configuration and software installation I realized that I forgot to install the RAID driver. Regarding to the [installation instructions](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=5390291&swItemId=MTX_2255f7f90adc4db089499186b2&swEnvOid=4176#tab3) the driver must be installed on the OS installation. This seems reasonable to me if I want to install the OS on a RAID array. But is it obligatory? How can I install it without re-installing my system?

Comment: Are you sure that the driver isn't simple included with an additional RPM?  This problem might be as simple as yum install $package.

Comment: @RustyWeber There's no repository which contains this driver. However there is also a RPM package located [here](https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/spp/2015.10.0_supspp_rhel7.2_x86_64/). It seems that it installs the kernel module but it is not loaded at start and inserting it manually leads to a system crash.

Comment: Duh, I realized that this actually is a valid RPM repository. However there's still no documentation how to use the rpm.